# How to access and modify previous commands (bash history) in Termux

Tags: keyboard, terminal, bash

I use Termux on my Fairphone 2 and I want to speed up working with it. What slows me down is not having an up arrow key that I can use to access the last command in my bash history. I can do `!!` `!7` and so on, but most of the time I don't want to actually repeat the commands, I just want to do something similar. I know some keyboard shortcuts to work with my bash history but they require a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, which none of my keyboards have. I use

- AnySoftKeyboard
- Hacker's Keyboard
- AOSP Keyboard

None of them have up arrow or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys

At the moment, I select and copy text by touching, but this is still slow.

How can I access my previous commands more quickly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [Termux help page](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Touch_Keyboard) for how to input arrow keys using the VolumeUp button, VolumeDown for Ctrl and some additional shortcuts!

Volume Up+W → Up arrow key

Comment: Congratulations for your app, mister.

Answer (score 2):

You said you use Hacker's Keyboard. If you turn the device into landscape mode Hacker's Keyboard does indeed have all four arrow keys along with ctrl & alt.

Comment: I use AnySoftKeyboard and it has up arrows on the code section :)

Answer (score -1):

Volume UP + Q to add Ctrl, esc, tab, alt Keys on Termux

Comment: I seem to get a printed `q` if I do that